# If wordpress widget is not active, show message

Tags: plugins, widget, wordpress

I'm writing plugin and in there I need to check if one widget in use or not. If the widget is in use that's great, but if it isn't I want to show error message.

The code what I tried is like this, but it isn't working. I don't get either message.

```
function my_widgie_detect()  {
  if ( false === is_active_widget( 'testimonial' )) {
    // do something here if the widget isn't active;
    echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p>No active</p></div>';
  } else {
    echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p>Active</p></div>';
   }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_widgie_detect' );
```

So how to recognize whether the widget is on, and if not wordpress will show a message?

Answer (score 2):

I have a client of mine who wanted to check if there's search widget activated into the sidebar or not from the template file so here's code, I guess this what you need! and I hope it will help others too!

```
<?php if(is_active_widget(false,false,'search')){
echo "Search Widget is activated"; //We don't need to place the search box here, since we have already into the sidebar.
}else{
get_search_form();
}
?>
```

Comment: Dont use init or wp_head hook to output the result like you and another user did on their code, use a template hook to output your result.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working like this:

```
function check_widget() {
    if( is_active_widget( '', '', 'testimonial' ) ) { // check if search widget is used
        //yay! active
    } else { echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>Widget is not active! Remembet to activate it here!</p></div>'; }
}

add_action( 'init', 'check_widget' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `wp_head` action, so your message div will be in head section and won't display... Take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference to use another action, or simply modify your template.